# Presentation of the additive group of the rational numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, rational-numbers, group-presentation

We know that $\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\sim$, where the isomorphism is a ring isomorphism and the equivalence relation is defined as

$$(a,b)\sim(c,d)\Longleftrightarrow ad=bc$$

Then the relation is stated in terms of the integers' multiplication. So, if I want to give a presentation for the additive group of $\mathbb{Q}$, how should I modify the presentation

$$\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\cong\, \langle a,b|aba^{1}b^{-1} \rangle$$

as I can't use the multiplication? The equivalence relation that defines $\mathbb{Q}$ can be stated in additive terms as

$$(a,b)\sim(c,d)\Longleftrightarrow \begin{cases}a=nc\\b=nd\end{cases}$$

where of course $nx$ stands for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x$, but I have no idea as how to insert it in the presentation. I'm in doubt that the additive group of $\mathbb{Q}$ is different from that of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, but it seems to me that fractions should be identified on the (additive) group structure independently of the subsequent definition of the multiplication.

Comment: Note that the rationals are not finitely generated as a group, so the presentation of $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$ you give cannot (easily) be turned into a presentation of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: I had heard of that, but I can't understand why, as $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Your first sentence is false. This is not a ring isomorphism, it is just a bijection between two sets.

Comment: As @DerekHolt mentions, your first sentence is false.  Indeed, the group of nonzero rational numbers under multiplication is not finitely generated.  (It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$, where the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the group $\{-1,1\}$, and each $\mathbb{Z}$ summand is the cyclic group generated by a prime number.)

Comment: Well, now that I think about it, it is obvious. $\Bbb{Z}\times(\Bbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{Q}$ is only a bijection. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: I think this is a great example of a shift in thinking people often struggle with early in undergraduate maths, from an emphasis on something's identity through *construction* (e.g. 'oh awesome we can define real numbers only using pure set theory!') to an emphasis on *structure* where we don't usually 'care' what a given object is 'made out of' in terms of underlying 'material', but care tremendously about wether algebraic structure is preserved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is not a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, or indeed any finite product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. By the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^N$ has a free component (which is a product of finitely many $\mathbb{Z}$'s) and a torsion component.

If $\mathbb{Q}$ were isomorphic to such a quotient, it couldn't have a torsion component because $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have any torsion (there is no integer $n$ and nonzero element $x$ such that $nx=0$). However, $\mathbb Q$ is not free because for any element $x$ and any integer $n$ there is an element $y$ such that $ny=x$; this is not true for free abelian groups. We can see a simple example where this fails in a free abelian group in the element $x=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$; there is no element $y$ such that $ny=x$ for any $n>1$.

Any abelian group is a quotient of a free abelian group, but for $\mathbb{Q}$ we would need a free abelian group with infinitely many generators. In particular, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ won't work.

Comment: Or alternatively, it cannot be a quotient of such a product since it is not finitely generated.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Essentially this is a proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated using the classification.

Comment: You don't need the classification theorem to prove that $\mathbb Q$ is not finitely generated; it simply follows from the fact that every finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ is cyclic, and $\mathbb Q$ is not a cyclic group.

Answer (score 9):

By the way, a presentation of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is

$$\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots \mid x_n^n=x_{n-1}, \ n \geq 2 \rangle.$$

To understand why, it is possible to consider the morphism induced by $x_n \mapsto \frac{1}{n!}$.

For more information, see Johnson's book, *Presentations of groups*, Chapter 5.7.

Comment: Or in additive notation, $\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots \mid n x_n = x_{n-1}, n \ge 2\rangle$.

Comment: Note that the proof in Johnson's book is not super-trivial. (I mean, fine, it's not that hard, but it's a couple of pages long.) Just in case a reader was wondering, as I did, if they should just be "seeing" the answer in a totally trivial way.